# Android - how to register a new FontConfig using FFmpegKitConfig.setFontDirectory

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg

I am using [ffmpeg-kit](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit) to burn a subtitle into a mp4 file , based on their tips [here](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/wiki/Tips), I need to register a font or specify a `fontconfig` configuration under `Android` , but I dont know how to do that.

in the tips , they suggest to use `FFmpegKitConfig.setFontDirectory` to register a new FontConfig, so I tried to write the below code :

```
String cmd = "-i " + videoPath + " -vf subtitles=\"" + subtitlePAth + ":force_style='Alignment=10,Fontsize=18\" " + 
   outputVideoPath;

Map<String, String> mapping= new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapping.put("fontName.ttf", "fontName");

FFmpegKitConfig.setFontDirectory(getApplicationContext(),fontDirectoyPath,mapping);

FFmpegKit.executeAsync(cmd, new FFmpegSessionCompleteCallback() {

     @Override
     public void apply(FFmpegSession session) {

     }
 }, new LogCallback() {

     @Override
     public void apply(com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.Log log) {


     }
 }, new StatisticsCallback() {

     @Override
     public void apply(Statistics statistics) {              

     }
 });`
```

but still I am getting this log when run this code

```
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0xe4bc04c0] Using font provider fontconfig[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0xe4bc04c0] 
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0xe4bc04c0] fontselect: failed to find any fallback with glyph 0x0 for font: (Arial, 400, 0)[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0xe4bc04c0]
```

any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying a font in the `force_style` directive. Try adding a `FontName=fontName` option there.

Also, I don't see the real values you use but your font name mapping may not be correct as well. Font name mappings have a `customName` -> `realName` format. Your example sets `fontName.ttf` as custom which is okay but also odd a bit. It has an extension at the end. If that's the value given then `force_style` directive must have `FontName=fontName.ttf`.

`ffmpeg-kit` has a separate repository for test applications at https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit-test. Test applications provided there have a Subtitle tab to test burning subtitles. You can see how `FFmpegKitConfig.setFontDirectory` is invoked and used there.